# Right meta tag for designer

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta

There are meta tags "copyright" (for site owner) and "author" (for content author)

But which is the right html5 tag for the html/css webdesigner?

Is there even one?

Comment: Depends on the opinion, _voting to close it!_

Comment: What opinion? Im just searching for the fitting meta tag.

Comment: Yes, what if I tell you to use copyright tag, someone else might say, use author tag. Then what? again 50 50 chances. HTML5 has nothing to do with it. :) It is just based on your own thing. If you're the holder of the website, use any of them. If you're just a developer, ask your boss! :)

Comment: I design a theme for phpBB and want to insert my copyright link to the theme.
But not the one for the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual HTML meta tag is like

```
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright reserverd and all that stuff" />
<meta name="author" content"I wrote this post for Stack Overflow" />
```

You see, HTML5 has nothing to do with either *copyright* or *author*. They're just to add the meta description for the page. HTML5 would render them both in the head and you're good to go, CSS has nothing to do here since you're not showing this meta tag to the user unless you put it in a `code` block.

Untill then, they're both just meta tags to add more details for your web page to allow Old search engines to query your website. But even Search engines don't use them, they scan your content directly.

The only thing that the HTML5 developer should care about would be the attributes of the `meta` element. Which are `name` and `content`.

For more on such things, always search for MDN [html_element] they've got the solution ready for you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

#### Adding meta tag for copyright

Adding the copyright in the meta tag is not a good thing to do here. What you should do is to include that as a sub child of the `footer` element. Like this

```
<footer>
   <div>&copy; 2014 - All rights reserved</div>
</footer>
```

This would be enough for the user to know, that you're having the rights reserved for this template and he must ask for the permission. `&copy;` would generate an HTML for copyright sign. You can include more text if you like to. That would be enough, meta tag won't be shown to the user and won't be more like it. Since user won't see it, he would think the template is Open Source.

Comment: The footer thing is a very good point :)

Comment: Yes, HTML is a very specific and broad topic. You should search for such good stuff on MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) at first! :)